# How can I send the content of a textarea to the textarea of "codepad.org"?

Tags: html, textarea, codepad

I want to send the content of a text area from a webpage to the text area in [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/).
How can I do that ?
[This](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/281396/alternative-to-form) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357224/passing-data-from-one-textarea-to-another-on-a-different-page-using-post) link did not help in doing this ....

If this is not possible, then how can I use "codepad.org" in other webpages ...... ???

Answer (score 1):

Unless the site has coded specific support for it (which I don't think codepad does), you cannot provide pre-defined values for the form elements, nor can you modify the textarea from your code.

I would create a paste and then embed it into your website using frames and the specific URL it gives you for your new paste.